# MySQL, find double rows with one other matching parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I constantly add information about pictures. If a picture in a category is my best ever, I want it to represent that category. Since I add many pics, I have a hard time to remove all the old "best picture flags" and would like to find them in a better way. I have searched but never really found a solution, so I keep scrolling through my 500+ categories to find doubles.

```
ID    Category   Best_pic
1     A          no
2     B          no
3     C          no
4     A          yes
5     B          yes
6     C          no
7     A          yes
8     B          yes
9     C          yes
```

So I want my search to return the rows 4,5,7 and 8, all rows where the column Best_pic is yes and there is more than one row with the value in column Category.

I really hope I made it clear, I have had this problem for a few years, but the pictures tend to be so many it is getting hard to handle this without a proper sql-question. :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Category IN (
    SELECT Category  
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE Best_pic = 'yes' 
    GROUP BY Category 
    HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
)x AND Best_pic = 'yes'
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked briliantly! :-) You just saved me a lot of time :-)

Comment: I was actually trying to, now I hope I found the right way to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

select t.* from test t JOIN (
select cat_id from test where flag='yes' group by cat_id having count(id)>1
) as a ON a.cat_id=t.cat_id where  t.flag='yes'

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try this solution as well, even if I found one working below :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.best_pic = 'yes' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.category = t.category and
                    t2.best_pic = t.best_pic and
                    t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

With an index on `t(best_pic, category, id)`, this should be the best performing solution, under most circumstances.

Comment: Thank you very much for your initiated comment, I will try your solution as well. :-)